# Apache Spark: I always got org.apache.axis.AxisFault: (404)Not Found when using google-spark-adwords

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm still a newbie in Apache Spark dev.

I'm using apache spark to query data from google ads words using *spark-google-adwords*. But, I always got this **org.apache.axis.AxisFault: (404)Not Found**

I'm using Scala 2.11 and latest stable Apache Spark. I've tried to look for the solution for this problem, but I still couldn't find out the cause.

Regards,

Comment: can you add some code pls?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by adding a copy of axis2.xml to classpath and overriding few connection manager params as follows:

```
HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
params.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(20); //SET VALUE BASED ON YOUR REQUIREMENTS/LOAD TESTING etc

MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.setParams(params);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    ConfigurationContext configurationContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("**PATH TO COPY OF AXIS2.XML**");
    configurationContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

credit : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4807